# register NT service in transaction

Tags: c#, .net, transactions

I have built an NT service which will be deployed on a group of servers in our organization.  From a central application, likely a web application, I would like to be able to register, unregister, start and stop the services.  If possible, I would like to do so reliably, in a transaction, so that if one operation fails everything is rolled back, similar to how a transaction in SQL service would work.  Is there a mechanism to manage OS resources in a transaction? If so, how?   I would be building this on the .net 4.5.1 framework.

Comment: Do you mean you want to start services on multiple servers in one hit and if one start fails none of the services shall be started etc.?

Comment: Yes, I want to investigate if that is possible.  I know that there is a Windows Kernel Transaction Manager, and a Distributed Transaction Coordinator.   So I'm interested to know what kinds of operations can a) be committed/rolled back in a transaction and b) what ones can be performed in transactions across systems.  Starting/Stopping and registering NT services are the operations I am interested in.